# Email validation on KEYUP event does not work

Tags: jquery, css

I have an input to enter an email.  As soon as I finish entering the email, I want validation to be done, so I use the `KEYUP` event.

But somehow the validation is not triggered.

Please give a hand.  Thanks!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8yL2v7u/)

JS

```
$('.newsletter-signup input').on('keyup', function(){
    var valid = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(this.value) && this.value.length;
   /*  $('#valid').html('It\'s'+ (valid?'':' not') +' valid'); */
   if (!valid) {
        $('#valid').addClass("show");
   }
   else {
   }
});
```

CSS

```
#valid {
  color: red;
  display: none
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="newsletter-signup">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<br />
<div id="valid">Required</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation actually works. There is something with your CSS.

Consider trying it this way:

```
$('.newsletter-signup input').on('keyup', function(){
    console.log('Validating...');
    var valid = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(this.value) && this.value.length;
   /*  $('#valid').html('It\'s'+ (valid?'':' not') +' valid'); */
   if (!valid) {
        $('#valid').show();
   }
   else {
      alert('Email is valid !');
      $('#valid').hide();
   }
});
```

To show/hide validation error message, I am using jQuery `show()/hide()`.

```
// instead of this
$('#valid').addClass("show"); 

// it is better to use this
$('#valid').show();
```

And when the input value is valid, I believe it makes sense to hide that block with `$('#valid').hide();`.

There is a small `alert()` I've added just to check it works; please remove it.

Actually, another good approach would be to use the validation on `blur` event - this is when your input loses focus (e.g. you go to next input on the page or simply do mouse click somewhere on your page, but not on the input):

```
$('.newsletter-signup input').on('blur', function(){ ... });
```

In this case, when your input loses focus - validation is triggered, instead of doing it every time you click on the button.

Happy Hacking :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `show` class property is being overwritten and you can currently see it happen in your code. The style gets added to the element, but you can see the `display` part is "lined out". Also if you're using jquery, you can just use an if statement and toggle the class you want. One way to do this would be to use `!important`. Here's a quick example:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bL2pao37/

```js
$('.newsletter-signup input').on('keyup', function() {
  var valid = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(this.value) && this.value.length;
  
  if (!valid) {
    $('#valid').toggleClass("show");
  }
});
```

```css
#valid {
  color: red;
  display: none
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newsletter-signup">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<br />
<div id="valid">Required</div>
```

Comment: Thanks justDan for sharing experience!